# Can I add a scrollbar to a flextras DropDownList?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder4.5

My GUI has a `<flextras:DropDownList />` that gets filled with an ArrayCollection that gets populated in my business layer.  In this instance, it is used to list the 12 provinces in Canada.

I've read through https://www.flextras.com/MobileComponents/Docs/asdocs/com/flextras/mobile/dropDownList/DropDownList.html and I'm aware that I could set requestedRowCount to 12, however this drop down is placed in a crowded VGroup and 12 options would just look silly and overlap other components, which it cannot do due to requirements.  The default of 4 options fits well in my current interface, but accessing all of the options isn't very intuitive.

A scrollbar would be perfect, but I haven't found anything suggesting this is possible.  Maybe another component would work?  Does anyone have any advice on this matter?  I can edit and post code, as this is a prototype mobile app, but I really don't think it's necessary...

Edit:

```
        <s:HGroup width="100%" styleName="ddlInfo">
            <s:Spacer width="2%"/>
            <flextras:DropDownList id="ddlProvince" width="80%" height="60%"
                                   dataProvider="{ddlPop.getProvinceDDL()}"/>
        </s:HGroup>
```

This is the ddl.  Here's where it gets the data:

```
    public function getProvinceDDL():ArrayCollection{
        var provinces:Provinces = parisLookup.getProvinces();

        for each(var prov:Province in provinces){
            provinceDataProvider.addItem({label:prov.ProvinceName,data:prov.ProvinceID});
        }

        return provinceDataProvider;
    }
```

Comment: Adding code would maybe clear it up a bit ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flextras DropDownList is a mobile conversion of the Flex DropDownList.

A scrollbar already exists in the drop down, which is in essence just a pop up with a list in it.    However, it is likely you are using our DropDownList in a mobile project; and the default scrollbar skin is hidden until you start scrolling.

If you want something more visual, you can create your own scrollbar skin.  You can either set this scrollbar skin globally in your app using CSS, or apply it solely to the DropDownList's drop down with a custom skin class to the Flextras DropDownList.

Comment: I see it now, and you're absolutely right, it's hidden until you click and start scrolling.  I say 'click' because I haven't tested this on a device yet at all, only through FlashBuilders' device emulation.  I appreciate the quick response, thanks again.